# Delete lines in perl

Tags: perl

I am new to perl and have no previous programming experience with any other programming language. I am trying to delete/skip few line using a do-while loop. I am trying to delete/skip data between two tags: `<worker>` and `</workers>`.

Code:

```
if($work=/^<worker>/)
{
   do
       {
         delete $work[$i];
                  ++$i;
                     }
       print $work,"\n";
}
```

Comment: How is $work declared ? Is it an array ?

Comment: There is no "do-while" loop in that code.

Comment: That equal sign `=` in `if($work=/^<worker>/)` is probably meant to be the binding operator `=~`. Also, using `delete` on arrays is deprecated.

Comment: Insted of `delete $work[$i]` you'd probably want `splice(@work, $i, 1)` or something similar depending on the initial value of `$i`.

Comment: Depending on the size of the data, you might want to try ie the module [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) to help you with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to skip data between tags `<workers>` and `</workers>`. You need to use .. in regular expression

This is a one liner that does it

```
perl -ne 'print unless /<workers>/../<\/workers>/' <file_name>
```

If you want to do it in the script, add this line after reading a line from the file

```
next if /<worker>/../<\/workers>/;
```

You can start perl with this very good [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/brian_d_foy/perl-university) by ***brian d foy***

Comment: Thank you for your help that was quick and helpful. I also have one more question if for eg i have <A>ABNDFD</A> how to just print ABNDFD

Comment: @nandini It looks like you are parsing a xml file, i will suggest you to use a module like XML::simple with which you can read a xml and convert it into a hash. Anyway, for your question the answer is use regular expression. `if($line =~ /<A>(.*?)<\/A>/) {$var = $1;}` `$var` will contain everything that comes between the two tags. I highly recommend reading the presentation i mentioned in the Answer, all these will become trivial for you

Comment: thanks a lot and I will surely go through the presentation that you have mentioned

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<>) {
  print unless m|<worker>| .. m|</workers>|;
}
```

Seems slightly strange to start and end on different tags. Should they both be 'worker' or 'workers'?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have data like:

```
my $x = <<END;

Text to keep
<worker> text to be deleted </worker>
Text to keep again
<worker>
Text to be deleted
</worker>
END
```

If you want to remove `<worker></worker>` tags as well:

```
$x =~ s/<worker>.*?<\/worker>//g;
```

If you need to keep tags:

```
$x =~ s/<worker>.*?<\/worker>/<worker><\/worker>/g;
```

However, this will work only if you can guarantee `<worker>` tags are not nested. Following string will cause error:

```
<worker> lalala <worker> bababa </worker> lalala </worker>
```

To do this work really good and safe you need to use parsing modules like `HTML::TreeBuilder` or `XML::Twig`

Comment: This was helpful, In also have 1 more question? how to print term between two html tags. Eg- <A>ABCFE</A> how to print only ABCFE

Comment: `$text =~ /<A>(.*?)<\/A>/si; print $1`

Comment: @yko--Thanks a lot I appreciate your help