# How to delete a bunch of lines in perl (adapting a known one-liner)?

Tags: perl

**context:** I'm a beginner in Perl and struggling, please be patient, thanks.

**the question:** there is a one-liner that seems to do the job I want (in a cygwin console it does fine on my test file). So now I would need to turn it into a script, but I can't manage that unfortunately.

The one-liner in question is provided in the answer by Aki here [Delete lines in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145362)

```
perl -ne 'print unless /HELLO/../GOODBYE/' <file_name>
```

Namely I would like to have a script that opens my file "test.dat" and removes the lines between some strings HELLO and GOODBYE. Here is what I tried and which fails (the path is fine for cygwin):

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (THEFILE, "+<test.dat") || die "error opening";
my $line;
while ($line =<THEFILE>){
next if /hello/../goodbye/;
print THEFILE $line;
}
close (THEFILE);
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot read from the file and print to it at the same time. That will overwrite your data. If you want to alter the file, use the `-i` switch, or do it explicitly by printing to a new file.

Comment: Also, is there something wrong with the one-liner you are showing? What is your question, really?

Comment: Yes I know it overwrites data, I'm simply rewriting the lines I want to keep as-is, and skipping the ones I don't want.  The one-liner is fine, but I want to turn it into a script, how to do that is my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your one-liner is equivalent to the following

```
while (<>) {
    print unless /HELLO/../GOODBYE/;
}
```

Your code does something quite different. You should not attempt to read and write to the same file handle, that usually does not do what you think. When you want to quickly edit a file, you can use the `-i` "in-place edit" switch:

```
perl -ni -e 'print unless /HELLO/../GOODBYE/' file
```

Do note that changes to the file are irreversible, so you should make backups. You can use the backup option for that switch, e.g. `-i.bak`, but be aware that it is not flawless, as running the same command twice will still overwrite your backup (by saving to the same file name twice).

The simplest and safest way to do it, IMO, is to simply use shell redirection

```
perl script.pl file.txt > newfile.txt
```

While using the script file I showed at the top.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have now tried it and the shell idea works perfectly. Best wishes.